Upper bound for 1-Wasserstein distance between standard uniform and other distribution on $[0,1]$
I want to use the following metric to measure the distance between the standard uniform distribution and any other probability distribution on $[0,1]$.
$$\int_0^1 |F(x) - x| dx$$
$F(x)$ is the cdf of some distribution on $[0,1]$ and $x$ is the cdf of the standard uniform distribution. This is essentially the 1-Wasserstein distance. I want a proof that an upper bound for this distance is $1/2$ or show $\int_0^1 |F(x) - x| dx \leq 1/2$, but I haven't been able to come up with a complete solution. Would anyone have any ideas how that could be proven?

Your own solution is on the right track, yet is not fully rigorous (or it is still incomplete). Below is a two-step proof that has its root on standard real analysis principles.
Step 1: $F$ is a simple function
In this case, restricted on the interval $(0, 1]$, $F(x)$ takes the form
\begin{align*}
F(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^nc_iI_{(a_i, b_i]}(x), \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}
where $n \geq 1$, $0 = a_1 < b_1 = a_2 < b_2 = \cdots = a_n < b_n = 1$, $0 \leq c_1 < c_2 < \cdots < c_n \leq 1$. Since $F$ is of piece-wise constant form $\eqref{1}$, the goal inequality becomes
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = 1}^n\int_{a_i}^{b_i}|c_i - x|dx \leq \frac{1}{2}. \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align*}
To analyze the summand in $\eqref{2}$, we consider the following three cases:
Case 1: $c_i \leq a_i$
In this case,
\begin{align*}
\int_{a_i}^{b_i}|c_i - x|dx = \int_{a_i}^{b_i}(x - c_i)dx 
= \frac{1}{2}(b_i^2 - a_i^2) - c_i(b_i - a_i) \leq \frac{1}{2}(b_i^2 - a_i^2).
\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align*}
Case 2: $a_i < c_i < b_i$
In this case,
\begin{align*}
& \int_{a_i}^{b_i}|c_i - x|dx = \int_{a_i}^{c_i}(c_i - x)dx + \int_{c_i}^{b_i}(x - c_i) dx \\
=& c_i(c_i - a_i) - \frac{1}{2}(c_i^2 - a_i^2) 
+ \frac{1}{2}(b_i^2 - c_i^2) - c_i(b_i - c_i) \\
=& c_i^2 - (a_i + b_i)c_i^2 + \frac{1}{2}(a_i^2 + b_i^2) \\
\leq & \frac{1}{2}(b_i - a_i)^2 \leq (b_i - a_i) - \frac{1}{2}(b_i^2 - a_i^2).
\tag{4}\label{4}
\end{align*}
Case 3: $c_i \geq b_i$
In this case,
\begin{align*}
& \int_{a_i}^{b_i}|c_i - x|dx = \int_{a_i}^{b_i}(c_i - x)dx 
= c_i(b_i - a_i) - \frac{1}{2}(b_i^2 - a_i^2)  \\
\leq & (b_i - a_i) - \frac{1}{2}(b_i^2 - a_i^2). \tag{5}\label{5}
\end{align*}
Denote $\sup\{i: c_i \leq a_i\}$ by $i_0$, which is the maximal index of intervals on which $y = c_i$ is completely dominated by $y = x$.
If $i_0 = n$, i.e., $y = F(x)$ is completely dominated by $y = x$ on $[0, 1]$, it then follows by $\eqref{3}$ that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = 1}^n\int_{a_i}^{b_i}|c_i - x|dx \leq \sum_{i = 1}^n\frac{1}{2}(b_i^2 - a_i^2) = \frac{1}{2}b_n^2 - \frac{1}{2}a_1^2 = \frac{1}{2}. 
\end{align*}
If $i_0$ does not exist, i.e., $y = x$ is completely dominated by $y = F(x)$ on $[0, 1]$, it then follows by $\eqref{5}$ that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = 1}^n\int_{a_i}^{b_i}|c_i - x|dx \leq \sum_{i = 1}^n(b_i - a_i) - \sum_{i = 1}^n\frac{1}{2}(b_i^2 - a_i^2) = 1 - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}. 
\end{align*}
If $1 \leq i_0 < n$, i.e., $y = F(x)$ is completely dominated by $y = x$ on $[0, b_{i_0}]$, while $y = F(x)$ may intersect $y = x$ or dominates $y = x$ on $(b_{i_0}, 1]$, it then follows by $\eqref{3}$ -- $\eqref{5}$ that
\begin{align*}
& \sum_{i = 1}^n\int_{a_i}^{b_i}|c_i - x|dx \\
\leq & \sum_{i = 1}^{i_0}\frac{1}{2}(b_i^2 - a_i^2) + \sum_{i = i_0 + 1}^n(b_i - a_i) - \sum_{i = i_0 + 1}^n\frac{1}{2}(b_i^2 - a_i^2) \\
=& \frac{1}{2}b_{i_0}^2 + 1 - a_{i_0 + 1} - \frac{1}{2}(1 - a_{i_0 + 1}^2) \\
=& \frac{1}{2} - a_{i_0 + 1} + a_{i_0 + 1}^2 < \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\eqref{2}$ holds for simple distribution function $F$.
As it can be seen, the rigorous algebraic proof is quite verbose. Alternatively, if we look at the inequality from a geometrical standpoint, $\eqref{2}$ simply says the area of the region bounded by $y = x$ and $y = F(x)$ is not greater than the area of the right triangle formed by the diagonal line of $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ and its edges, which is almost trivial (try to apply the reflection principle).
Step 2: General CDF $F$
For the general (non-negative) $F$, it can be approximated from below by simple functions, i.e., there exists a sequence of simple functions $\{F_n(x)\}$ such that $F_n(x) \uparrow F(x)$ for every $x \in (0, 1]$ (cf, Theorem 13.5 in Probability and Measure (3rd edition) by Patrick Billingsley).  Because $F$ is nondecreasing, $F_n$ is of form $\eqref{1}$ (note that without the nondecreasing condition, approximation functions need not to be stair-wise, so subsequent arguments may become invalid). It then follows by Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem (the condition of DCT is straightforward to verify) and $\eqref{2}$ that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 |F(x) - x|dx = \int_0^1 \lim_{n \to \infty}|F_n(x) - x| dx 
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 |F_n(x) - x| dx \leq \frac{1}{2}. 
\end{align*}
This completes the proof.

This simple, intuitive question deserves a simple solution.
The following is a proof in pictures: the second figure below tells the whole story.  But to help convince you it is simple, rigorous, and does not mask some subtle analytical error, I spell out the details.  There's nothing more complicated going on here than the most elementary Euclidean geometry, but I do make some remarks about measurability to assuage those who might be concerned about "pathological" distributions $F$ where $F(x)-x$ wiggles infinitely often between positive and negative values (a situation that is automatically handled with the geometric approach but requires detailed and subtle analysis otherwise).

Let $\mathcal U\subset[0,1]\times [0,1]$ (the "under" set, shaded cyan in the pictures) be the points in the unit square below the diagonal and the graph of $F:$
$$\mathcal U = \{(x,y)\mid 0\le F(x)\lt y \lt x\le 1\}.$$
Similarly let $\mathcal O$ (the "over" set, shaded red) comprise the points between the diagonal and the graph of $F$ lying above the diagonal,
$$\mathcal O = \{(x,y)\mid 0\le x \lt y \lt F(x) \le 1\}.$$

Consider the function $h:\mathcal U\to [0,1]\times[0,1]$ that sends each point $(x,y)\in\mathcal U$ to its reflection,
$$h(x,y) = (y,x).$$
The following are straightforward:

The image of $h$ is a subset of the unit square because all coordinates lie between $0$ and $1.$

$h$ preserves area, because it is the restriction of an area-preserving linear function to the (measurable) set $\mathcal U.$

The image of $h$ lies within the upper half triangle of the unit square $$\Delta = \{(x,y)\mid x \le y\}$$ (where the second coordinate exceeds the first), because by construction when $(y,x)\in h(\mathcal U),$ $y \lt x.$

The area of the upper half triangle cannot exceed $1/2,$ because that triangle and its reflection are disjoint and comprise a proper subset of the unit rectangle whose area is $(1-0)\times(1-0)=1.$



The crux of the matter is that

The image of $h$ is disjoint from $\mathcal O:$ $$h(\mathcal U)  \cap \mathcal O = \emptyset.\tag{*}$$

Let's prove this.  What are the elements of this intersection?  They must have coordinates $(x,y)$ for which both $x \lt y \lt F(x)$ (belonging to $\mathcal O$) and $F(y) \lt x \lt y$ (that is, $(y,x)$ belongs to $\mathcal U$). By transitivity of inequality, $$F(y)\lt F(x),$$ but at the same time $$x\lt y.$$ This is impossible because $F$ is a non-decreasing function, QED.

The question asks for an upper bound on the area of the region between the diagonal $\{(x,x)\mid 0\le x \le 1\}$ and the graph of $F,$ which is expressed as the integral of their absolute difference $|F(x)-x|.$  This region consists of $\mathcal U$ (the part below the diagonal), $\mathcal O$ (the part above the diagonal), and its boundary, which is a subset of the diagonal and the graph of $F$ -- both of which have zero area.  Consequently, writing $|*|$ for the area of any (measurable) set and bearing in mind the crucial result $(*),$
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1|F(x)-x|\,\mathrm dx &= |\color{red}{\mathcal U}| +|\color{blue}{\mathcal O}| = |h(\color{red}{\mathcal U})| + |\color{blue}{\mathcal O}| \\
&= |h(\color{red}{\mathcal U}) \cup \color{blue}{\mathcal O}| + |h(\color{red}{\mathcal U})\cap \color{blue}{\mathcal O}| \\
&= |h(\color{red}{\mathcal U}) \cup \color{blue}{\mathcal O}| + |\emptyset|\\
&\le |\Delta|+0 = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{aligned}$$
The inequality follows from the fact (obvious by the definitions) that the region $h(\mathcal U)\cup \mathcal O$ is a subset of $\Delta.$

Consider the case of $F$ stochastically dominating the uniform distribution, i.e., $F(x)\geq x$. Then:
$$
\int_0^1|F(x)-x|\,\text{d}x = \int_0^1 (F(x)-x)\,\text{d}x\leq \int_0^1 (1-x)\,\text{d}x = \frac{1}{2}
$$
Now consider the case of $F$ being stochastically strictly dominated by the uniform distribution, i.e., $F(x)< x$. Then:
$$
\int_0^1|F(x)-x|\,\text{d}x = \int_0^1 (x-F(x))\,\text{d}x\leq \int_0^1 (x-0)\,\text{d}x = \frac{1}{2}
$$
Now consider the case of $K\geq 1$ inner crossing points $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^K$ between $F(x)$ and $x$, with $x_0=0<x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_{K}<x_{K+1}=1$. Then, if $F$ stochastically dominates the uniform distribution in $(x_{k-1},x_k)$, we have that:
$$
I_k = \int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k}|F(x)-x|\,\text{d}x = \int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k} (F(x)-x)\,\text{d}x\leq \int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k} (x_{k}-x)\,\text{d}x = \frac{1}{2}(x_k-x_{k-1})^2
$$
Else, we have that:
$$
I_k = \int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k}|F(x)-x|\,\text{d}x = \int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k} (x-F(x))\,\text{d}x\leq \int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k} (x-x_{k-1})\,\text{d}x = \frac{1}{2}(x_k-x_{k-1})^2
$$
It is the same bounding expression. Then:
$$
\int_0^1|F(x)-x|\,\text{d}x = \sum_{k=1}^{K+1}I_k \leq \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{K+1}(x_k-x_{k-1})^2\leq\frac{1}{2} 
$$
This last inequality comes from the fact that, under the constraint $0\leq x_{k-1}<x_{k}\leq 1$, $\max\sum_{k=1}^{K+1}(x_k-x_{k-1})^2=1$

It is possible to have more irregular distributions that do not fall in any of the three cases you covered.

@Zhanxiong, can I claim that the integral is a sum of simple functions like I did in my own answer?

@spencergw I think the direction is correct but it may need some enhancement for a complete rigor (say, cite monotone convergence theorem).  I can add an answer when I get time.

@Zhanxiong thank you. I just edited my previous answer to allow more than one crossing points.

@JohandeAguas Your edit makes the scope of $F$ slightly broader, however, it is still not broad enough. For example, $F$ may have countably many intersections with $y = x$. As another example, $F$ can be strictly increasing, making your argument invalid, as in this case $F$ is not a constant on any interval.

@JohandeAguas In addition, even assuming $F$ is simple, your solution missed a third case , that is $F$ is neither dominated by $y = x$ nor dominates $y = x$ on $(x_{k - 1}, x_k)$.  Please check my answer for details.

@Zhanxiong do you mean that $F$ might have countable infinite many intersections with $y=x$? I agree, that case is out. I changed some inequalities to strict inequalities to cover the case $F(x)=x$ at any $(x_{k-1},x_k)$. Thanks!

@Zhanxiong, for step 2 in your proof, can you say for example |F_n(x) - x| \leq 1, and thus use the DCT?

@spencergw Yes. In more detail, start with $\int_0^1 |F_n(x) - x| dx \leq 1/2$ for all $n$ by Step 1, so $\limsup_n \int_0^1 |F_n(x) - x| dx \leq 1/2$, now apply DCT on the LHS of this inequality.

@spencergw I may have misunderstood your question -- are you asking how to check DCT condition?  If so, this is because $\int_0^1|F(x) - x|dx \leq \int_0^1(|F(x)| + |x|)dx \leq \int_0^1 (1 + 1)dx = 2 < \infty$.

@Zhanxiong, it's $|F_n(x) - x|$ that needs to be bounded right?

@spencergw Yes, you're right.  But obviously $|F_n(x) - x| \leq |F_n(x)| + |x| \leq |F(x)| + |x| \leq 2$, which is bounded for every $n$.

I came up with this since posting the question. Is it reasonable?
Let $[0,1]$ be partitioned into sets $[a_1, a_2), [a_2, a_3), ..., [a_{K-1}, a_K]$ where $0 = a_1 < a_2, ..., < a_K = 1$. The function can be rewritten as
\begin{equation*}
    \int_0^1 |F(x) - x|dx = \underset{k \rightarrow \infty}{\text{lim}}\sum_{k = 1}^{K-1} \int_{a_k}^{a_{k + 1}} |c_k - x| dx
\end{equation*}
for some $c_k$ a constant and $c_k \in [a_k, a_{k + 1})$. Now
$$\int_{a_k}^{a_{k+1}} |c_k - x| dx = \int_{a_k}^{c_k} (c_k - x) dx + \int_{c_k}^{a_{k + 1}} (x - c_k) dx$$
$$= \left[c_kx - \frac{x^2}{2}\right]^{c_k}_{a_k} + \left[\frac{x^2}{2} - c_kx \right]_{c_k}^{a_{k + 1}}$$
$$= c_k^2 + c(-a_k - a_{k + 1}) + \frac{1}{2}(a_k^2 + a_{k + 1}^2)$$
$$\leq a_k^2 + a_k(-a_k -a_{k + 1}) + \frac{1}{2}(a_k^2 + a_{k + 1}^2)$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}(a_k^2 + a_{k + 1}^2) - a_k a_{k+1}$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}(a_k^2 - 2a_k a_{k + 1} + a_{k + 1}^2)$$
$$= \frac{1}{2} (a_{k+1} - a_k)^2$$

It doesn't really even get off the ground because you don't explain how to find the $a_k$ or the $c_k,$ nor is it clear the initial equality is correct.  (In fact, it's not: you need to place restrictions on the gaps among the $a_k.$)  Indeed, your final expression will, in the limit, sum to zero, so you have "proven" that all distributions are the uniform distribution!
